# Any way to change react-native-timeago color to white?

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native-timeago to display how long ago a post was written. So far, it is working fine, but I am trying to incorporate a dark theme on my app and the timeago text is black - this doesn't work out well.

Here is the code I am using to try and change the color:

```
<View style={styles.timeContainer}>

      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> <TimeAgo time = {this.state.date_created} /> </Text>
                        
</View>
```

the styling:

```
timeContainer: {
        paddingLeft: 20,
        color: '#FFFFFF',
    },
```

It is still black. I even dm'ed the creator of the package on twitter to ask him if it is possible to turn it white, because I am having no luck. Let me know if you know how to do it/know of an alternative package I can use to make the text color white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply adding style props to timeago worked. I don't know why it didn't last time I tried, but this time It did:

```
<TimeAgo style={{color: '#696969'}} time = {this.state.date_created} />
```